# Negating statements.

Tags: logic

In Book of Proof, by Richard Hammack.

We are asked to negate the statement: I don't eat anything that has a face.
The answer was I eat some things that have a face, to me this is correct, but he then goes on to say that it's negation is not: I eat everything that has a face.

The supposed false negation if true would make the original statement wrong, so why is the negation wrong?

Comment: If it is not true that I eat everything that has a face, then it could be true that I don't eat anything that has a face or I eat only some things that have a face but not everything that has a face; if a negation of a statement is not true, the statement must be true; $P\lor\lnot P$

Comment: There is a mistake in the question. Hammack says "(Note: If your answer was “I will eat anything that has a face.” then that is wrong, both morally and mathematically.)" and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the original statement is ambiguous.

> I don't eat anything that has a face.

It could mean:  'It is not true that I eat anything with a face', i.e. 'It is not true that I eat everything with a face' ... and then the negation would be 'I eat anything with a face', i.e. 'I eat everything with a face'

However, it could also mean that 'It is not true that I eat something with a face' .. in which case the negation is 'I eat something with a face'

Personally, I think the latter is a bit more intuitive (in which case *you* would be right), but you can also imagine the following conversation:

A: "Wow. You are so disgusting: You eat would anything with a face!"

B: "No, I don't. While it's true that I eat some things that have a face, I don't eat just anything with a face"

So, what $B$ is saying here is that $B$ is not eating everything with a face, and hence the denial of that would be what $A$ is claiming: that $B$ would eat everything with a face. And so this would be in line with the former interpretation.

The moral: "anything" is notoriously ambiguous, especially in the context of a negation.

Answer (score 0):

Quantifiers :

$\exists$ for there exists.

$!\exists$ for there exists exactly one

$\forall$ for all.

some thing(s) implies that there exists an element of the set of things that have faces which they'll eat.

everything implies forall elements in the set of things that have faces  they'll eat it.

Answer (score 0):

Logic is valid for formal statements and trying to negate in sentences of human language is incorrect and precarious. The only correct way to negate 'I don't eat anything that has a face' is 'It is not true that I don't eat anything that has a face'.

The sentence 'I eat some things that have a face' is a reasonable interpretation, but 'I eat everything that has a face' is an unreasonable interptetation. After all, there could be something with face that he doesn't eat.

Answer (score 0):

According to Book of Proof free pdf version by Richard Hammock, "a statement is a sentence or
a mathematical expression that is either definitely true or definitely false." (p. 35).

Assuming we all know what having a face means (have an axiom for it, an agreed upon definition without proof), either the object has a face or it does not have a face. The sentence is definitely true or definitely false.

The dilema is in how we interpret the word "anything".

The sentence could mean I eat everything with a face" or "I eat something with a face".

In the free pdf version of Book of Proof, we are asked to "[T]ranslate each of the following sentences into symbolic logic." (p. 59).

Let P = I eat anything that has a face.

Then $P \lor \lnot{P}$.

On one hand, if we interpret the word "anything" to mean "everything", then the negation of P would be $\lnot{P} =$ I eat some things that have a face".

On the other hand, if we interpret the word "anything" to mean "something", then the negation of P would be $\lnot{P} =$ I eat everything that has a face".